# How to add a function in AngularJS-factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

[image: View of the settings.]

I took over an AngularJS (Cordova) project being a newbie in this area. Now I have to add a new "wheel-item" called "Eingepasst", which is different to the existing ones like i.e. "Partnerspiel" (see picture).

When having clicked the button on top-right a valued called "Spielwert" (here: 22) will be written to the 'Model' (talking about MVC).

The related part of the code is inside a "factory"-JavaScript-file" called 'game.factory.js':

```
angular.module('app').factory('Game', function (Settings, Round)
{

    function MODEL()
    {
        return {
            type:
            [
                {
                    key: 'EI',
                    value: 'Eingepasst',
                    rate: Settings.get('eingepasstRate'), //from there the minus-value is derived for adjusted
                    variants:
                    [
                        { key: 'E0', value: 'Regulär', multiplier: 1, rate: Settings.get('eingepasstRate') }
                    ]
                },
```

Unfortunately I could not figure out, where 'key', 'value', 'multiplier' and 'rate' derive from...

However I want to add a function call here to run some calculations inside the code snippet above. What do I have to do here? Please be as detailed as possible...

Comment: It looks like `Game.MODEL()` simply returns a JSON object.  And you can access this by `var model = Game.MODEL(); var variantKey = model.type.variant[0].key;`  Need more details and context before we can help you.  Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks, so far. What I would like to achive is to add ng-disable in order to avoid being able to click "Spieler 1" - "Spieler 4" next to "Gewonnen" and "Verloren". Secondly I want to add ng-class in order to change the colour of the aforementioned buttons/options. How to achieve this?