# Setting a button to 'active' is not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, sass

Next to the question I have described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008268/how-to-add-a-function-in-angularjs-factory), I am trying a different approach.

Being a newbie in AngularJS/Cordova/Ionic I want to achieve different things when having clicked the "Eingepasst"-button, which will have a different logic compared to "Gewonnen" or "Verloren" (see screenshot).

Starting with the easiest approach I want to achieve: I want to set the "Eingepasst"-button to active next to changing the variable 'adjustedYesNo' to 'true'.

This is the code from the html-file:

```
<div class="padding">
    <div class="button-bar">
        <button ng-click="round.won=true" ng-class="{'active':round.won == true}" class="button button-outline">Gewonnen</button>
        <button ng-click="round.won=false" ng-class="{'active':round.won == false}" class="button button-outline">Verloren</button>
        <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="{'active':adjusted.adjustedYesNo() == true}" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code of the controller.js-file:

```
$scope.adjusted = function (adjustedYesNo)
{
    console.log("adjusted before: ", adjustedYesNo);
    var adjustedYesNo = false;
    console.log("adjusted afterwards: ", adjustedYesNo);
    return adjustedYesNo;
}
```

And here the relevant part of the CSS:

```
.button {

  border-radius: 10px;

  &.button-light {
    color: $ci-green;
  }

  &.button-outline {
    @include regular;

    color: $ci-white;
    border-color: $ci-white;

    &.activated {
      background-color: rgba($ci-white, .1);
      border-color: $ci-white;
    }

    &.active {
      border-color: $ci-white;
      background-color: $ci-white;
      color: $ci-green;
    }
  }
```

So what do I have to change in detail that the value 'adjustedYesNo' is being 'true' when landing in the function (in fact 'adjustedYesNo' is undefined) next to why is the "Eingepasst"-button not changing to color 'white' when having clicked?

[image: screenshot]
[image: console.log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different problems in follow line:

```
 <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="{'active':adjusted.adjustedYesNo() == true}" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
```

On click you call  `adjusted()` but don't pass a parameter, this is why `adjusteYesNo` is undefined first time

To get the right design you call `adjusted.adjustedYesNo()`
 But I don't think that this is a defined function. I assume you want to access `adjusteYesNo`. Then i suggest to do this with a `$scope` variable.

```
$scope.adjusted = function (adjustedYesNo)
{
    console.log("adjusted before: ", $scope.adjustedYesNo);
    $scope.adjustedYesNo = adjustedYesNo;
    console.log("adjusted afterwards: ", $scope.adjustedYesNo);
    return $scope.adjustedYesNo;
}
```

So you can get your design with `ng-class="{'active':adjustedYesNo}"`

**Edit:**

To get only one highlighted button you can do something like that (depends on your requirements):

```
 <button ng-click="round.won=true" ng-class="{'active':round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Gewonnen</button>
 <button ng-click="round.won=false" ng-class="{'active': !round.won && !adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Verloren</button>
 <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="{'active':adjustedYesNo}" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon, this seems to work :-D. Bonus ;-) question: What needs to be done in order to have only ONE of those three buttons "Gewonnen", "Verloren" or "Eingepasst" being highlighted/set to 'active'/changed to colour 'white'?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="{'active':adjusted.adjustedYesNo() == true}" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
```

Change this line  to

```
 <button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="{'active':adjustedYesNo == true}" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
```

then in controller change the function to

```
$scope.adjusted = function ()
{
   console.log("adjusted before: ", adjustedYesNo);
   $scope.adjustedYesNo = false;
   console.log("adjusted afterwards: ", adjustedYesNo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code.

```
<button ng-click="adjusted()" ng-class="adjustedYesNo?'active':''" class="button button-outline">Eingepasst</button>
```